# Is there a way to deactivate the us of created_at and updated_at?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I just want to deactivate the fields created_at and updated_at of my gorm model, haven't been able to find it in the docs.

Getting this errors when trying to create rows in the db:

```
Error 1054: Unknown column 'created_at' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The created_at, id, updated_at, deleted_at fields are embedded into your model by embedding the gorm.Model into your struct.

So, to disable them instead of doing

```golang
type Product struct {
  gorm.Model
  Code  string
  Price uint
}
```

do

```golang
type Product struct {
  ID    uint `gorm:"primarykey"`
  Code  string
  Price uint
}
```